# show member from the partment use CI

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I'm new for CI, I'm had 2 table calls 'partment' and 'user'. I try to display parment_name where brand_id column = 0 in Partment table and member name in User table, but in partment table i have 2 column is partment_id and brand_id, any partment have brand_id = 0 is the brand, any partment have brand_id = other partment_id excerpt it and unlike 0 is the partment. But user table just only have partment_id, so how show all value user in the Brand, but not show name of the Partment
Sorry for my bad English
Partment Table

```
+-------------+--------------+----------+
| partment_id | parment_name | brand_id |
+-------------+--------------+----------+
|           1 | brand 1      |        0 |
|           2 | partment 1   |        1 |
+-------------+--------------+----------+
```

User Table

```
+---------+--------+-------------+
| user_id |  name  | partment_id |
+---------+--------+-------------+
|       1 | name 1 |           2 |
|       2 | name 2 |           1 |
+---------+--------+-------------+
```

i want show like this:
 |   brand 1  |
 |   name 1   |
 |   name 2  |

Thanks all Guys!

Comment: why should `user_id` 2 be on your list ? there is no `partment_id` related to ...

Comment: sorry, my mistake i'm just edited